# Javascript call by value and call by reference

Tags: javascript

I'm hoping this is not going to be a duplicate post. I tried all the posts, and though I was able to get what I wanted, I'm unable to understand why it's working this way.

Use case: I would like to create a Javascript nested object from a script. For this, from one of the stack overflow posts, I landed in the below script

```
var o = {};
  function setByPath(obj,path, value) {
    var parts = path.split('.');
    var o = obj;
    if (parts.length > 1) {
      for (var i = 0; i < parts.length - 1; i++) {
          if (!o[parts[i]])
              o[parts[i]] = {};
          o = o[parts[i]];
      }
    }

    o[parts[parts.length - 1]] = value;
}

setByPath(o,"path.path2.path","kunjdab");
console.log(o);
```

The output for the first one is :

`o[path][path2][path] = "kunjdab"`

and then I tried to modify this just to learn this, and tried this:

```
      function setByPath(path, value) {
        var parts = path.split('.');
        var o = {}
        if (parts.length > 1) {
          for (var i = 0; i < parts.length - 1; i++) {
              if (!o[parts[i]])
                  o[parts[i]] = {};
              o = o[parts[i]];
          }
        }

        o[parts[parts.length - 1]] = value;
        return o
    }

var o =  setByPath("path.path2.path","kunjdab");
console.log(o);
```

The output of the second one `o[path] = "kunjdab"`

The first snippet works just fine but the second one doesn't. I'm not sure as to why. Can someone help me?

I did, read the Javascript Call by reference and Call by Value. In the first case, the reference of `o` will be passed as value to the function. But I still am unable to understand why the first one works and the second one doesn't.

Comment: why doesn't it work?  what is happening?  we can't help if you don't specify desired output

Comment: What do you expect it to do? You aren't returning anything.

Comment: It seems that in the second case function does not return a value (it's void).

Comment: Edited. Also, updated with the Output.

Comment: I think you are trying to get the value of the `o` that is defined within the function. Even if you weren't overwriting it in the `var o = setByPath ...`, it is locally scoped to within the function. You need to return it from the function. Put the line `return o` as the last line of the function.

Comment: In the second case you just returning the last object initialized in a loop.
Modify this to:
var o, obj; o = obj = {};

And return obj;

Comment: Yes, I know I'm returning the last initialized object. How do I return the chained object?

Comment: Vova, it works. But why?